# getting confused with trying to insert nesting objects

Tags: javascript

Currently trying to build a javascript form that converts the inputs into JSON. I've managed to create objects that allow multiple keys/values to be entered however I'm struggling to get my head around the logic and code for nesting a child object within an object.

```
let objects = [];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let infoBoxOne = document.getElementById('key').value // store the key into a variable
        let infoBoxTwo =  document.getElementById('value').value // store the value into a variable

        const lastObject = objects[objects.length-1] // finds the last object in the objects array
        const objectValues = Object.entries(lastObject) // gets all the keys and values 
        const lastKeyValuePair = values[values.length-1]; // stores the last key and value entered into a variable

    })
})
```

So my initial idea was to find the last key/value within the last object that was added and use something like `Object.create()` or `push()` to insert the data. Is there an easier way of achieving this?

---

edit: here's a jsfiddle showing what I have exactly so far https://jsfiddle.net/9jrzLxnm/

---

Secone edit: idea of what I'm trying to achieve

```
{
  {
    "firstObject":'FirstObject'
  },
  {
    "lastObject": {
      "infoBoxOne": "JlastObject",
      },
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you are just looking for `lastObject[infoBoxOne] = infoBoxTwo;` ?

Comment: You never give `values` a value.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what `btn2` is trying to do (btw: use descriptive element ids!). What do you want the 2 fields to add to the output `object` when you click `btn2`?

Comment: The aim of btn two is to take the two values of infoBoxOne and infoBoxTwo and add them as a new child object inside of the last object that's in the 'objects' array.

```

{
    "lastObject": {
      "infoBoxOne": "JlastObject",
    },
}

```

Comment: hm.. one last question then.. what to do if last object has several children? where to place the child in that sense?

Comment: and what if the last object already had a key/value like `{"lastObject":"foo"}` what happens if you add a child to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok firstly you have to set the desired location to place a child object as an object itself.. *then* the rest is intuitive

My example is on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Y0ursTruly/sx2rLy70/16/)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let childKey = document.getElementById('key').value // store the key into a variable
        let childValue =  document.getElementById('value').value // store the value into a variable

        const lastObject = objects[objects.length-1] // finds the last object in the objects array
        const values = Object.entries(lastObject) // gets all the keys and values 
        const [key,value] = values[values.length-1]; // stores the last key and value entered into a variable
        lastObject[key]={} //turning place to put child into an object
        lastObject[key][childKey]=childValue //placing the nested child
        document.forms[0].reset();
        listToJson();
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks! this makes a bit more sense now